# Should we rename tags of games which have been "converted"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, the game Super Street Fighter IV was renamed in the Steam library to Ultra Street Fighter IV.  SteamDB supports this, as did Capcom.   They converted Super Street Fighter IV to Ultra Street Fighter, despite the fact that Super Street Fighter IV is it's own game.

IN this case, should we rename SSFIV to USFIV?   This is odd, because the game was formally converted to USF4, so players who did not convert to USFIV will still have a USFIV in their libraries, with it actually being SSFIV

Comment: What is the official title? Generally we should go with that, and use synonyms as appropriate.

Comment: This is weird. The game itself is called SUPER STREET FIGHTER IV, the upgrade is called ULTRA STREET FIGHTER IV, but Capcom has made it so SUPER STREET FIGHTER IV is now ULTRA STREET FIGHTER IV, despite it retaining only the former's features.

Comment: Is there a game called Super Street Fighter IV anymore, then?

Comment: Doesn't exist on Steam anymore though it is considered a separate game than Ultra, because it has different gameplay elements and characters. So for example, I can't ask "How do I use delayed wake-up with Rolento" as a SSFIV question because those two gameplay features are only available in USF4

Comment: Possibly a dupe of http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/lets-merge-tagstreet-fighter-4-and-tagsuper-street-fighter-4-to-tagstree/9896#9896 (my answer to this question remains the same; for what it's worth others agreed in comments, but I'm not sure it's been implemented)